# Elasticsearch change text to date field

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Here, I am trying to add datefield. earlier i created the date field as text field but, now when i am trying to change to date field i am getting below  error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [metadata.modifiedAt] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "mapper [metadata.modifiedAt] cannot be changed from type [text] to [date]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Please check the screenshot attached.

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the field data type, you have to create a new field. Changing field type is a breaking change, but you can add a new date field in your index.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the field type but you can add a new field to the existing index.

```
PUT index_name/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "metadata.modifiedAt_new": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

After adding the new field the new documents will have the `metadata.modifiedAt_new` field as a date field type.

To update existing documents you can run the following API. It will update the whole existing documents.

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```